# How can i make "1/1" to stay as "1/1" and not "01-Jan" when exporting from list to csv?

Tags: python-3.x, export-to-csv

when i export from a list to CSV strings such as "1/1" or "1/3", they are automatically converted to dates, ie "01-Jan".

How can i keep as "1/1"?

Here is my code:

```
import csv

my_list = [["1/1", "1/3"]]

with open("my_csv.csv", "a", newline="") as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    for i in my_list:
        writer.writerow(i)
```

Thanks.

Comment: can't replicate, what are you viewing the csv with?

Comment: If you’re opening it excel, it may helpfully be converting what is in the csv file. Have you tried opening the csv file in a text editor?

Comment: Prefix it with an apostrophe which prevents Excel converting it to an data. `["'1/1", "'1/3"]`, The effect is that Excel interpretes it as _text_.

Comment: @NegativeChameleon i edited my code. what i get in the csv is 01-Jan in cell A1, and 01-Mar in cell A2. I want to just see 1/1 and 1/3. I tried to change the cell format to "text", but then i am getting this: 43466 in cell A1 and 43525 in cell A2.

Comment: @JoopEggen your solutions gives me '1/1 on the csv file, i just need to have 1/1.

Comment: But Excel will read it as "1/1" without conversion to date.

Comment: the apostrophe method is [officially suggested](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/stop-automatically-changing-numbers-to-dates-452bd2db-cc96-47d1-81e4-72cec11c4ed8). Although I can imagine this creates problems for other software that should read the csv... If you want an Excel file in the first place, have a look at e.g. `pandas`, [pandas.DataFrame.to_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html).

Comment: Thanks to all - yes, it looks that the only solution is to just something to make excel stop thinking that it is a date.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with python. Most likely the program you're viewing the .csv in is formatting the output.

Also, are you sure you want the output that way? Currently the output is:

```
1,/,1
1,/,3
```

You can remove the loop and just write the list to the file

```
import csv

my_list = ["1/1", "1/3"]

with open("my_csv.csv", "a", newline="") as csvfile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
        writer.writerow(my_list)
```

for this output:
`1/1,1/3`

Comment: Thanks, but as per above, i edited my code - my_list is actually a list of lists.